# Preventing dust spots when staining outside

Tags: staining, outdoor

I'm getting ready to stain a small table I'm making, and everything I've read says that you need to make sure your environment is dust-free to prevent spots. However, I live in a small condo in the city and have been doing all of my work outside on the patio. I don't have a good interior space to do the staining without completely fumigating our place. How can I stain my table without getting it covered in dust spots? I currently have a very dark stain+poly, so it will probably require multiple coats. I haven't opened it yet though, so I could probably return it if there's another more suitable product.

Comment: Your stain + poly is actually coloured varnish and IMO it should be called that in plain English on the label. Stain is actually something that colours wood, not covers the wood with a coloured layer which this (and "gel stain") do. Not that these are necessarily bad products, they're necessary and have their uses, but I'm in favour of called a spade a spade in finishing because there's already so much to cause confusion!

Comment: Anyway, on to your dust problem. Since you can be sure there'll be some airborne dust where you're forced to work the best preventative is probably to construct a dust tent using a simple framework and old well-washed sheets to prevent as dust, as much as possible, from landing in the drying varnish. Actual stains sidestep this issue because they are in the wood, not on the wood surface, and dry very much more quickly too.